# Регистрация пользователя

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo "<h1>Регистрация</h1>";
$submit = strip_tags($_POST['submit']);
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
$repeatpassword = strip_tags($_POST['repeatpassword']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip = $_POST['ip'];
if ($submit)
{
 // check for existans
if($name&&$password&&$repeatpassword&&$email)
{

if ($password==$repeatpassword)
{

//check name
if(strlen($name)>15||strlen($name)<4)
{
echo "Логин должен быть от 4 до 15 символов!";
}
else
{
 //check password
if (strlen($password)>25||strlen($password)<6)
{
echo "Пароль должен быть от 6 до 25 символов";
}
else
{

if (isset($_POST['name']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
}

if (isset($_POST['password']))
{
$password = $_POST['password'];
}

if (isset($_POST['email']))
{
$email = $_POST['email'];
}

if (isset($_POST['date']))
{
$date = $_POST['date'];
}

if (isset($_POST['ip']))
{
$ip = $_POST['ip'];
}

 //encrypt password
$password =md5($password);
$repeatpassword =md5($repeatpassword);

//open database
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","vladon12");
mysql_select_db("testgame");
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `users` (name,password,email,date,ip) values('$name','$password','$email','$date','$ip')");

die ("Добро пожаловать в игру =) Нажми <a href='index.php'>здесь</a> для продолжения
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
background-color: #A6CAF0 ;
color: #330033 ;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 2%;
}
</style>
</head>
</html>");

}

}

}
else
echo "Пароли не совпадают!";

}
else
echo "Введите <b>все</b> поля";

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="ru" dir="ltr">
<p>
<head>
<style>
body{
background-color: #A6CAF0 ;
color: #330033 ;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 2%;
}
</style>
<title><?php echo $config['title'];?></title>
<meta http-equiv = "content-type" content = "text/html; charset = <?php echo $config['coder'] ; ?>" />
</head>

<body "alink = '#0000ff' link = '#0000ff' vlink = '#0000ff' ">
<p style ="text-align: center;">

<form action="index.php?page=register" method="post" name="form">
<p>*Логин: <br><input name="name" type="text" size="20" maxlenght="40"></p>
<p>*Пароль:<br><input name="password" type="password" size="20" maxlenght="40"></p>
<p>*Пароль:<br><input name="repeatpassword" type="password" size="20" maxlenght="40"></p>
<p>e-Mail:<br><input name="email" type="text" size="20" maxlenght="40"></p>

<p><br><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться"></p><br>
<br><a href="index.php"><<назад</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Не заносит пользователя в бд, что делать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Prikol, Расставьте отступы в коде. В данный момент ваш код нечитаем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `users` (name,password,email,date,ip) values('$name','$password','$email','$date','$ip')");
```

Поменя на

```
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `users` (name,password,email,date,ip) values('$name','$password','$email','$date','$ip')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Что выведет?

Comment: Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'

Comment: Ой извините=) Я в бд сделал pass а в пхп пишу password =)

Comment: Ну вот, видите) Всегда пользуйтесь этим для отладки запросов, всякое бывает)

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте так:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (name,password,email,date,ip) values('$name','$password','$email','$date','$ip')";
echo $sql;
$result = mysql_query ($sql);
if (!$result) echo mysql_error();
```

В результате чего увидите какой запрос отправляется в базу. Наверняка с ним что-то не так. А так же, если запрос не удался, то на выходе будет еще и ошибка. Т.е. будете знать где именно в запросе ошибка.